# How to check Amazon SNS, Amazon API server log

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121566/amazon-sns-url-works-on-browser-but-not-from-android-app)

In summary,

I send the correct request to amazon API though, It doesn't work somehow (return 400Error).

I did everything in my application side.

Now, I would like to know the Amazon Server log to research into the problem.

How can I check the amazon API server log, or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your previous question is not entirely correct in my opinion. It's just a generic answer about HTTP 400 codes, and not very helpful in your situation. Did you look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/CommonErrors.html) to see the official list of error response codes from SNS and their meanings?

If you want logs of your AWS API calls you need to enable [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/).

Comment: Thanks I found out the error reason it was because of MalformedQueryString. However I wonder why it happens on only Android not iPhone. I guess it is related with encoding though ..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366002/the-value-of-a-query-string-parameter-may-not-contain-a-delimiter