# the value of a query string parameter may not contain a '=' delimiter

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, titanium

Now I simplify the problem.

I try to directly copy and paste the query to confrim it use %3D instead of '='

```
    var xhrSNS = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload :function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("test Post query:" + JSON.stringify(e));
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText); 
        },
        onerror : function(e){
            Ti.API.debug("test Create PlatForm Endpoint registerPush error:" + e.error);
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText); 

        }       
    });

        getUrl = "http://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com?AWSAccessKeyId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&Action=CreatePlatformEndpoint&PlatformApplicationArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aap-northeast-1%3A776188326341%3Aapp%2FGCM%2Fmyapp&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2016-04-03T15%3A05%3A51.465Z&Token=APA91bEiaB-902cRmwwgCwoqi2jRIJzzTIZNB7XduELuBKit_WF29tN5twrVW5t1BHpj07ARgwjzoc-I5xVur5K6I6ZQcnoErguUyi-VBHvuI5eY9HS4jq1J6KbIC05Etoe8indjpY9X&Version=2010-03-31&Signature=DzxQpP%2BcALS91C53eia6ZkBhxg3lQ32ctqiEmqKwwLA%3D";
        xhrSNS.open('GET',getUrl);
        xhrSNS.send();
```

Please see the last letter of getUrl, it surely use '%3D'.

But return is the same.

It makes a complaint that sentence include '=' delimiter.

```
[DEBUG] test Create PlatForm Endpoint registerPush error:400 : Bad Request
[INFO]  <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
[INFO]  <Error>
[INFO]  <Type>Sender</Type>
[INFO]  <Code>MalformedQueryString</Code>
[INFO]  <Message>AWSAccessKeyId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&amp;Action=CreatePlatformEndpoint&amp;PlatformApplicationArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aap-northeast-1%3A776188326341%3Aapp%2FGCM%2Fmyapp&amp;SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&amp;SignatureVersion=2&amp;Timestamp=2016-04-03T15%3A05%3A51.465Z&amp;Token=APA91bEiaB-902cRmwwgCwoqi2jRIJzzTIZNB7XduELuBKit_WF29tN5twrVW5t1BHpj07ARgwjzoc-I5xVur5K6I6ZQcnoErguUyi-VBHvuI5eY9HS4jq1J6KbIC05Etoe8indjpY9X&amp;Version=2010-03-31&amp;Signature=DzxQpP%2BcALS91C53eia6ZkBhxg3lQ32ctqiEmqKwwLA= is not valid; the value of a query string parameter may not contain a '=' delimiter</Message>
```

-----------------------------adding until here-----------------

I am using Amazon SNS API

I made url like this it works well on browser.

```
http://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com?AWSAccessKeyId=AAAAAAAAAAAAA&Action=CreatePlatformEndpoint&PlatformApplicationArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aap-northeast-1%3A776188326341%3Aapp%2FGCM%2Fmyapp&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2016-04-01T21%3A06%3A29.861Z&Token=APA91bEiaB-902cRmwwgCwoqi2jRIJzzTIZNB7XduELuBKit_WF29tN5twrVW5t1BHpj07ARgwjzoc-I5xVur5K6I6ZQcnoErguUyi-VBHvuI5eY9HS4jq1J6KbIC05Etoe8indjpY9X&Version=2010-03-31&Signature=Dt9tXa0Rjl%2Ff6YxZ4JaPfsm%2BT%2BMX03gS712nIKKekAI%3D
```

However if I try from Android.

This returns 400 bad request.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>MalformedQueryString</Code>
<Message>AWSAccessKeyId=AAAAAAAAAAAAA&amp;Action=CreatePlatformEndpoint&amp;PlatformApplicationArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aap-northeast-1%3A776188326341%3Aapp%2FGCM%2Fmyapp&amp;SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&amp;SignatureVersion=2&amp;Timestamp=2016-04-01T21%3A06%3A29.861Z&amp;Token=APA91bEiaB-902cRmwwgCwoqi2jRIJzzTIZNB7XduELuBKit_WF29tN5twrVW5t1BHpj07ARgwjzoc-I5xVur5K6I6ZQcnoErguUyi-VBHvuI5eY9HS4jq1J6KbIC05Etoe8indjpY9X&amp;Version=2010-03-31&amp;Signature=Dt9tXa0Rjl%2Ff6YxZ4JaPfsm%2BT%2BMX03gS712nIWUekAI=
 is not valid; the value of a query string parameter may not contain a '=' delimiter</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>5b40d988-af34-577a-8839-96f04a217dec</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I think

> the value of a query string parameter may not contain a '=' delimiter

is the cause of problem though, I cant figure out how to fix it.

The same code works on iPhone.

it doesn't work only from android.

I made URL strings from this function

```
var array = {
    PlatformApplicationArn : Ti.App.global.androidArn
};
awsObj = getSignature("CreatePlatformEndpoint",date,awsUrl,event.registrationId,array);
    var getUrl = "http://" + awsUrl + '?' + awsObj.str_para + "&Signature=" + awsObj.encodedString;
Ti.API.info('GETurl :' + getUrl);
xhrSNS.open('GET',getUrl);


function getSignature(action,date,awsUrl,token,array){
    Ti.include('/jssha/jssha256.js');

    var base = {
        Action:action,
        AWSAccessKeyId : Ti.App.global.awsAccessKey,
        SignatureMethod : "HmacSHA256",
        SignatureVersion :2,
        Token: token,
        Timestamp : date,
        Version : "2010-03-31",
    };
    para = arrayMerge(array,base);

    var para_array = [];

    for(var pname in para){
        para_array.push(pname + "=" + encodeURIComponent(para[pname]));
    }
    para_array.sort();

    var str_para = para_array.join('&');
    var str_signature = "GET" + "\n" + awsUrl + "\n" + "/" + "\n" + str_para;

    console.log("str_signature:" + str_signature);

    HMAC_SHA256_init(Ti.App.global.awsSecretKey);
    HMAC_SHA256_write(str_signature);
    var array_hash = HMAC_SHA256_finalize();

    var str_hash = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < array_hash.length; i++) {
        str_hash += String.fromCharCode(array_hash[i]);
    }

    var awsObj = new Object();
    awsObj.encodedString = encodeURIComponent(base64encode(str_hash));

    Ti.API.info("awsObj.encodedString:" + awsObj.encodedString); // I have confirmed encodedString is correct here.
    awsObj.str_para = str_para;
    return awsObj;
}
```

Comment: The symptoms here make it look as if the user agent in titanium is badly broken and is trying to normalize the query string, which it should not do.  Note that SNS also accepts requests as `POST` instead of `GET`.  That is actually the more correct verb for this action, and the parameters would then be in the request body, not the query string.  That seems like a worthwhile approach to investigate.  You also appear to have a more serious problem you also need to address: `Ti.App.global.awsSecretKey` ... you're embedding your AWS credentials in your app?  That a very insecure design decision.

Comment: Working from the theory that the user-agent in titanium is actually modifying the request, I have a test site at https://echo.sqlbot.net/ that will echo the request you send, back to you in the response body, for just such purposes.  It might be useful to get a second opinion of what URL you're *really* sending with your request, by sending the same request, substituting my test server's hostname.  If my site shows `=` on the end, when you think you're sending `%3D` on the end, that should clearly point the finger at something on the android side behaving very badly.

Comment: Agree with Michael. A wild thought, have you tried to move Signature to the front of query string in getUrl? Perhaps Android just can't handle %3D in the end.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your great help. I send the same url like `https://echo.sqlbot.net/?AWSAccessKeyId=AAAAAA&_etc_& Signature=0Z%2FRmG58bxdtwtqAVEtEVjMPKI4MSG15WNk8Vb3XamY%3D`. I send `%3D` though it shows `=`

Comment: @Yangfan I changed the order of query and put signature in the middle of query, however same result.

Comment: @whitebear that is interesting.  Glad to have helped (a little bit, anyway).  URL encoding of query string parameters is interesting territory because in unambiguous cases, it is *not* always mandatory (`?foo=bar&assertion=foo=bar` has an obvious meaning, for example, that the key "assertion" has the value "foo=bar") but again for the user agent to un-encode something on the way out is very strange.  By contrast to SNS, the S3 API will (or did, back when I tested it) accept either `=` or `%3D` appearing in the signature, while `+` and `/` still require encoding.

Comment: So, my workaround recommendation (unless you can find the real source of this apparently-incorrect behavior) is either to use `POST` instead of `GET`, with the parameters in the request body and hopefully immune to this strange behavior... or use Signature Version 4 instead of V2 to sign the requests, since the signature in V4 is hex-encoded rather than base64.

Comment: I assume the android web browser itself does not have this problem for you -- only an issue from your code, right?  From my android (4.4.2) phone the `%3D` echoes back correctly.

Comment: @Michael android browser works OK. maybe  bad behaivor of titanium??? I will report to them after further investigate.

Comment: @Michael I am trying to use POST. You are familliar with POST request to amazon SNS ?? I send the POST request to the same server `http://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com` with parameter, however 404 returns.... I am familliar with titanium POST request though. I can't find the document about the POST request in amazon API document

Comment: Examine the response body, it will probably say `<UnknownOperationException/>` which means SNS didn't understand the request well enough to throw a meaningful error.  You will want to send the parameters in the request body, with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @Micael Thanks , I finally succeeded to send some queries and get some answers from server. but now it says timestamp is wrong `Timestamp 2016-04-06T06%3A18%3A35.614Z must be in ISO8601 format`. I know it is the problem of encoding, so I cancel the encoding process for each query, but then it returns signature error.

Comment: I have calculated signature according to this article when I use 'GET' http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html. Now I use 'POST' how can I calculate the signature ??? or is it correct to send query data without encoded?? (timestamp says it is bad, so there is no way though,,,,)

Answer (score 1):

URL in browser: Signature=Dt9tXa0Rjl%2Ff6YxZ4JaPfsm%2BT%2BMX03gS712nIKKekAI%3D

URL in Android: Signature=Dt9tXa0Rjl%2Ff6YxZ4JaPfsm%2BT%2BMX03gS712nIWUekAI=

Comment: However I use urlencode already. I added the article. please see getSignature function. And it works well on iPhone.

Comment: Then what is the `=` char at the end of the signature?

Comment: mmm... Somehow error messages include '=' char.  Ti.API.info('GETurl :' + getUrl) shows %3D instead of = , so I think url is correctly encoded.

Comment: I added this line `Ti.API.info("awsObj.encodedString:" + awsObj.encodedString);` at the end of function `getSignature();` and confirmed signature is correctly encoded.

Comment: it shows `awsObj.encodedString:WhFEAITvO1xVoBt%2BLfWcrGSsKPbJNpIQb0CLj7qloz8%3D` , `=` is correctly encoded.

Comment: mmmm .... '=' is enoded here`Ti.API.info('GETurl :' + getUrl);` however `xhrSNS.send();` returns error related with encoding... and ios it works wll, this happnes only Android..

Comment: I try very simple one and found it returns the same error, I added the top of the article.